# How to protect the executable perl files from PAR::Packer?

Tags: perl, perl-packager

I have created an executable Perl script file using the below command.

```
pp -x -o output.exe test.pl
```

The exe file was successfully generated. But when I extract the file using the below command I am able to see the source code.

```
unzip output.exe
```

Here I want to protect my Perl script. Even when I extract the file using PAR::Packer that should ask password to extract the file.

Please suggest your views on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. The code must be provided to Perl to be executed, so it must be available.

Comment: You should use other programming language to achieve desired result, as was indicated by ikegami Perl require source code be unencoded to be executed. Google for 'protection of executable file from reverse engineering' to compile information. You can start by reading following [article](https://www.cybrary.it/blog/0p3n/advanced-exe-multi-protection-reverse-engineering-free-tools/). Knowledgeable professional who knows how to use debugger and how CPU works (registers, assembly commands, binary codes) are capable to hack binary executables.